# How to resize the content of a smart object without affecting the parent document layout?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, file-size, smartobject

While working I’ll more than often just place documents as smart objects. Then I’ll end up with a colossal file size. I want to go into the smart objects and reduce its image size but consequently the parent psd will change the layer size of that smart object. I also don’t want to resterize those layers.

[image: before]
[image: smart object size before]
[image: smart object size after]
[image: after]

Comment: What happens if after you change the resolution, you update the width and height to the size of the previous resolution, (i.e, 12487 x 12000)?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the size of a Smart Object (embedded or linked) by changing the *Resolution* the size in the parent document should be unaltered.

If you on the other hand change the size by changing the *Width* or *Height* it will also change the size in the parent document.

[image]

(The same principle applies to images placed in InDesign by the way.)